# Pager alongside search form in Play! 2.3.3

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, model-binding

I'm using Play framework 2.3.3. On a page I have a list of entities alongside with filter form that uses standard play form binding and it works like a charm. But now I'd like to add pagination below the list. The problem is preserving form parameters when user clicks pager links below the list ('next' or 'prev').

Similar example 'Computer database' avoids form usage and handles parameters like simple method parameters. But my form is quite complex: it binds to `case class SearchForm(purposeId: Option[Long], placeIds: Seq[Long], since: Option[Date], till: Option[Date])`.

What is the best way to handle this situation without JS?

Comment: Are you using a POST to search or GET? It sounds like POST. Don't use POST, use GET, and put your params into query parameters which get extracted by the router. Then you can use the reverse router to easily generate next/previous links as the answer below does.

Answer (score 0):

simplePaginator.scala.html (only for test)

```
@(currentPage: Int, lastPage: Int, pageLink: Int => Call, width: Int = 5)

    @link(index: Int) = {
        <a href="@pageLink(index)">@{
            index + 1
        }</a>
    }


    @if(lastPage > 0) {
        <div class="pager">
            @link(currentPage - 1)
            @link(currentPage + 1)
            @link(lastPage)
        </div>
        <br>
    }
```

You have to provide pageLink function.

```
GET     /page         @controllers.PageController.index(pageIndex:Int ?= 0)
GET     /page/:pageIndex         @controllers.PageController.index(pageIndex:Int)
```

And call:

```
@simplePaginator(currentPage,lastIndex,controllers.PageController.index)
```

Comment: By `prev`/`next` I meant pager links below list, not browser buttons.

Comment: I changed to pagination. This is only simple prev/next. You can create more complex pagination toolbar with binary search. If you wish I can add example of implementation.